# Is it possible to produce wavefunctions for ordinary distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions

One of the fundamental principles of quantum mechanics is the existence of a complex function $\psi(x,t)$ which obeys Schroedinger's equation $\dot{\psi} = H\psi$. Here $H$ is a linear, complex operator. Since $H$ typically has the form $k\nabla^2 + V(x,t)$, for a complex constant $k$, that is, a wave equation, $\psi$ is generally called the wavefunction of the quantum system. If $V$ does not depend explicitly on time, the time dependence of $\psi$ amounts to a complex exponential, and the spatial part of the wavefunction alone, $\psi(x)$, contributes to probabilistic interpretations.

$\psi(x)$ is intimately connected to the calculation of configuration (physical) space probabilities. For example, the probability of finding a quantum particle between $x$ and $x+dx$ is postulated to be $|\psi(x)|^2dx$. Thus $|\psi(x)|^2$ plays the role of the quantum pdf in configuration space.

Expectations (which must be of Hermitian operators to be physically meaningful) however are *not* computed via $E[g(x) = \int_X g(x)|\psi(x)|^2dx$ as might be expected, but rather through the $L_1(X)$ inner product
$$
E[g(x)] = \int_X\psi^*(x)g(x)\psi(x)dx. 
$$

My question is whether or not there's a general way of reversing this reasoning: start with a pdf $f(x)$ and seek a 'wavefunction' $\psi(x)$ for which $E_f[g(x)] = \int_X\psi^*(x)g(x)\psi(x)dx$ for all measurable $g(x)$ on the configuration space (space of random variables) $X$. Note that this condition is enough to imply $f(x) = |\psi(x)|^2$ if we take $g = 1$.

One advantage of such a wavefunction representation would be the ability to link the inner product $(g,h) = E[g^*h]$ conventionally used in probability to the $L_1(X)$ inner product defined above.

Comment: I'm confused. $g(x)$ is presumably a scalar, so that the expectation very much is $E[g(x)]=\int_Xg(x)|\psi(x)|^2dx$. So $\psi(x)=e^{i\phi}\sqrt{f(x)}$.

Comment: No, $g(x)$ is an _operator_. Think of it as a matrix. Therefore, $g(x)$ is scalar, only if $\psi$ is an eigenvector of the $g(x)$.

Comment: @ALB: I guess your allowed to start with your $f(x)$, as long as the phase of the wave function doesn't matter. However, as soon as you get a coherent superposition of wave functions, you need to know their phases $\phi$ (as Alex pointed out).

Comment: @Semoi. You can of course generally write $\psi(x) = e^{i\phi(x)}\sqrt{f(x)}$; that's true for any complex function for which $\psi(x)|^2 = f(x)$. What Alex R. may have missed is the spatial dependence of $\phi(x)$, which matters when you demand that $$E[g(x)] = \int_X \sqrt{f(x)}e^{-i\phi(x)}g(x)e^{i\phi(x)}\sqrt{f(x)} \ dx$$ for non-scalar operators $g$.

Comment: @AlexR. see above.

Comment: Then I'm even more confused. If $g$ is an *arbitrary* operator, what does $E_f[g(x)]$ mean? I understand $\int_X \psi^*(x)g(x)\psi(x)dx$, where say, $g(x)$ could be the momentum operator which will differentiate $\psi(x)$. But then what is $E_f[g(x)]$ as a function of $f$? As in $E_f[g(x)]=\int_x g(x)f(x)dx$ (which makes no sense)? Also when you say that you're integrating over the space of random variables, that makes no sense. The usual quantum integral is over space, not random variables.

Comment: @Alb: Do you know this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116595/why-is-the-application-of-probability-in-qm-fundamentally-different-from-applica) This is not a direct answer to your question, however, it shows that the probability in standard statistics and qm are not identical.

Comment: @Semoi that's really interesting. So it looks like the answer is 'no' for all practical purposes.